# What's happened with Cardano Proof of University Diplomas in Greece?

Tags: metadata

Storing university diplomas was a novel major usability announcement for Cardano back in 2018. It's been over 3 years if my memory serves me right. The plan was to use an enterprise permissioned version of Cardano or something to that extent.

Did IOG do it? 
Did it work?

Comment: I personally think this is an excellent and on-topic question. I also remember this project and am curious of its current status. I'm voting to reopen this and started a discussion in the meta forum.